# How can I access the variable mapping used when bit-blasting?

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm modifying a tool which uses Z3 (specifically the Python API) to solve bitvector constraints. I need to use a particular external SAT solver instead of the internal Z3 one, so I'm first bit-blasting using the tactic

```
Then('simplify', 'bit-blast', 'tseitin-cnf')
```

after which I can relatively easily dump the clauses to a DIMACS file. The problem is mapping the resulting propositional model back to a model of the original constraints: as far as I can tell, the Python API doesn't provide a way to access the model converter corresponding to a tactic. Is this true? If so, can it be done using a different API, or is there an easier way altogether? Basically I just need to know how the propositional variables in the final CNF clauses correspond to the original bitvector variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds pretty special purpose. The easiest will likely be that you instrument the goal2sat conversion (and recompile Z3) to save a 
translation table in a file. I don't think any of the functionality exposed over the API would give you this information.

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to mention which is the translation table?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it without modifying Z3. Here is an example in python. (Based on an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059096/z3-and-dimacs-output) by Leonardo.)

```
from z3 import BitVec, BitVecSort, Goal, If, Then, Bool, solve
import math

x = BitVec('x', 16)
y = BitVec('y', 16)
z = BitVec('z', 16)

g = Goal()

bitmap = {}
for i in range(16):
    bitmap[(x,i)] = Bool('x'+str(i))
    mask = BitVecSort(16).cast(math.pow(2,i))
    g.add(bitmap[(x,i)] == ((x & mask) == mask))

g.add(x == y, z > If(x < 0, x, -x))

print g

# t is a tactic that reduces a Bit-vector problem into propositional CNF
t = Then('simplify', 'bit-blast', 'tseitin-cnf')
subgoal = t(g)
assert len(subgoal) == 1
# Traverse each clause of the first subgoal
for c in subgoal[0]:
    print c

solve(g)
```

For every position i of the bitvector x we introduce a new boolean variable xi and require that xi is equal to the i-th position of the bitvector. The names of boolean variables are preserved during bit-blasting.